How to place datalabels within container for recharts - PieChart when a label having longer text
I am using recharts library to plot pie chart in our react application. I have added the datalabels for each slice. The labels are cropping since it has larger length. Is there any way to wrap the labels or smartly place the labels within the container?

Source code is attached in this link
Stackblitz link

SVGs do not word wrap with CSS. You can use tspan in your text itself to create breaks in words but it will be arbitrary positions that you will have to pick. You can try using foreignObject + a div to render your labels as HTML and then using regular word wrapping, but positioning still might be difficult
